# Crash Report for Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, crashlytics, crash-reports

I am new to flutter. I developed one Wallpaper App using flutter and upload in playstore. Now i need to track crash report for that app. In Android have [crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/) to all report crash and more fearure's. Is [crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/) support in flutter ?. I looked [sentry](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sentry) plugin but it's not free. Any help Appreciable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sentry is currently the only solution provided by the Flutter team.

Crashlytics support is planned https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14765

**update**

There is now a community package with crashlytics support as well https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_crashlytics

Comment: With the description here https://flutter.io/cookbook/maintenance/error-reporting/ it is imho easy to set up a crash reporting solution without Sentry

Comment: Depends on what you mean with that. It's easy to to get error logs from Flutter but where/how do you collect them?

Comment: e. g. HockeyApp has an API for sending Crash reports, so from the sample code you only need to add the request to that and probably store some data temporary for the next startup of the app

Comment: Can you provide a link to HockeyApp?

Comment: sure, the link to post custom Crash reports is https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/api/api-crashes#post-custom-crashes

Comment: @Christian I haven't found a relation to Flutter.

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding, I wanted to say that with the sample code of flutter.io it is easy to set up a crash reporting with another service than Sentry. You get the data from Flutter, store it somewhere (db or flat file) and forward it with a simple HTTP POST request to the API of a tool like HockeyApp. I did it with my own API, so my code is not very helpful for the community.

Comment: @Christian yeah, sorry. Got it now :D

Comment: @Christian you said its easy to get crash data from Flutter. How can I do that?

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro the link https://flutter.io/cookbook/maintenance/error-reporting/ I posted describes the few code snippets you need to integrate into your app to get error reports. The only thing you need to add is to post these reports to your own webservice or a 3rd party API. It is not a one-liner like in many Crash-Libraries, but for me it was done in 2 hours.

Answer (score 8):

**note this:**

since April 2020 fabric crashlytics panel will no longer be supported so you have to use [firebase crashlytics panel](https://console.firebase.google.com/) instead

**solution:**

for that flutter team now has created [firebase_crashlytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics).
so you can use this library instead of the [flutter_crashlytics](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_crashlytics) which is the community version.